# Installing drupal 7 on IBM Bluemix

Tags: drupal-7, ibm-cloud

How to install drupal 7 on IBM Bluemix ? I tried to install using cf but not able to connect with mysql or any db.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Since basically it is a PHP based application you could use the PHP runtime on Bluemix. To get started you could take a look at [Deploy a Drupal Application on IBM BlueMix](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/02/17/deploy-drupal-application-ibm-bluemix/). However please note that the article was written when Bluemix was still a BETA, and I suggest you to use it as a starting point. Note also that the following:

> Please note:  At this time, BlueMix does NOT provide persistent file storage. In order to have custom themes and plugins persist with your instance of Drupal, you should save those themes and/or plugins within the application folder prior to pushing your application.

Is not true anymore. Now you can use the [Object Storage Service](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/object-storage/) to store all your files (images, documents, and more) in the cloud.

2. You can use a Docker container image to create a Drupal container. This is the solution I would recommend. Take a look at [Drupal Container on IBM Bluemix](http://blog.ibmjstart.net/2015/08/10/drupal-container-on-ibm-bluemix/?cm_mc_uid=11335133656114562151633&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1458978653) to see a step-by-step tutorial on how to run an official Drupal image from DockerHub on the IBM Containers platform within Bluemix, and then connect that Drupal instance to a database service running on Bluemix.